# Jquery Ajax - post huge string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i need to POST a huge string large about 3mb, is it possible to send it to php using not url params?

If i send it in url params the request reachs the size limit in url.

How can work around this? any clue?

thanks a lot.

Actually i'm doing it like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type:'POST',
.......
data:{string:3MB_string}
});
```

i'm using PHP and jQuery , and i wouldl ike to send the 3mb base64 string to php on a simple url, like `site.com/script.php`

The string is a File Reader API base64 image

this is an example of string but this won't reach the size limit it is not a 3mb is less cause troubling in pasting that to show you a 3mb, http://jsfiddle.net/QSyMc/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will need to use a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: 'some huge string here' },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('the request was successfully sent to the server');
    }
});
```

and in your server side script retrieve the value:

```
$_POST["value"]
```

Also you might need to increase the allowed request size. For example in your `.htaccess` file or in your `php.ini` you could set the [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) value:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Comment: i'm already sending that in this way :P @Darin Dimitrov and this cause url size limit reached

Comment: i mean i get console "you reached request limit"

Comment: @bombastic We're going to need more information then. What is the `URL` you are sending it too? What server side language is it using? etc.

Comment: You might need to increase the maximum allowed request size as well. I have updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov link for your answer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: +1 @DarinDimitrov sorry but data:{} is the playload? it doesn't puts params in the post url then?

Comment: @bombastic `data` is the data sent to the `send(data)` method of the [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object, which is the payload.

Comment: @crush has that somenthing to do with url params in a POST ?

Comment: @bombastic I'm explaining why it's not sent in the URL params. The URL is sent in the `open()` method, not the `send()` method. When you specify `type: 'POST'` in jQuery, you are telling it that you want to send the `data` as the payload, not as url params.

Comment: this is the string returned from php http://jsfiddle.net/QSyMc/ it is not 3mb troubling with copy and paste too huge a 3mb string

Answer (score 11):

Try with `processData` to false and a string representation of your JSON

```js
var data = { "some" : "data" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/script",
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(r) {
       console.log(r);
    }
});
```

From the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation :

> **processData** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) **will be processed and transformed into a query string**, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why you think this is necessary or why this would work?

Comment: var data = { "some" : "data" }; half json, half object?

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to use POST method. If the string is still to large, check you php.ini file to find out the maximum POST parameter size.

To change this value value, do any one of those:

**1. change values in php.ini**

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

**2.  or add this code to .htaccess file**

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Which one to use depends on what you have access to.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar problem. It wasn't the length of the query string but rather the number of variables I was passing to the server. The php.ini places a limit in the max_input_vars field to 1200 variables. In my case, I was exceeding that amount rather than the post_max_size amount. Had to go back and make the query more efficient and under the limit. I guess I could have raised the php.ini setting but I wound up with better code by disabling non-essential query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "YOUR STRING";
$.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { mystring: str },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```