# How to pass large string through ajax call to controller in MVC?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

How to pass large string data (stringified data) through ajax call to controller in MVC?

In my current scenario, my string is 820 KB. In controller, the string is received as `[{"Id":"2vwf35f!@#qad", .... name:"sdfs"}]`.

I can find `....` in between the string data at controller side.

Comment: You can use Ajax post method to post large string to the controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810063/jquery-ajax-post-huge-string-value

Comment: @AllenKing, I'm using ajax post only. When I inspect the data, I found some data is missing in the string. In between the string it is displayed as "...."

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Hi @AllenKing, addding the below code in config file fixed my issue

Comment: <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />

Answer (score 0):

This what i use to post data using Jquery ajax  call to my  Codeigniter controller.
You can send large amount of data using this method.

```
    var id=$(".id").val();
    var name=$(".name").val();
    var formData = {
        'id'              : id,
        'name'            : name,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=base_url()?>ControllerName/saveAjaxdata/",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(resultData)
        { 
         console.log(resultData);
        }
  });
```