# Jquery Ajax - post huge string value in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried this below link but not working in my server.
[Jquery Ajax - post huge string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810063/jquery-ajax-post-huge-string-value)

Comment: Welcome. Please provide more information, it'll be very hard to help you otherwise. Show the code you're using and explain what isn't working and what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_url",
            data: {string:3MB_string},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == undefined) {
                    alert("Error : 219");
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                if (data == undefined) {
                    alert("Error : 465");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error : 468 " + data.d);
                }
            }
        });
```